# Use pseudo element first-child in several articles inside a section

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to style only the first .mask div, but I can't find how to do that (besides giving another class and style it). Is there a way using a pseudo-element such as :first-child or :first-of-type?

I have this html:

```
    <section class="cont-content work" id="work">
        <h1>work</h1>
        <article class="view">
            <img src="images/g.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="mask">
                    <h2>Title</h2>
                        <p>subtitle</p>
                    <a href="#" class="info">Read More</a>
                </div>
        </article>

        <article class="view">
            <img src="images/m.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="mask">
                    <h2>title</h2>
                        <p>subtitle</p>
                    <a href="#" class="info">Read More</a>
                </div>
        </article>

        <article class="view">
            <img src="images/p.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="mask">
                    <h2>title</h2>
                        <p>subtitle</p>
                    <a href="#" class="info">Read More</a>
                </div>
        </article>          
    </section>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes

```
   #work article:first-of-type .mask
```

is what you are looking for then

Answer (score 0):

[CSS3 :nth-of-type() Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp)

```css
.view:nth-child(2) .mask {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<section class="cont-content work" id="work">
  <h1>work</h1>

  <article class="view">
    <img src="images/g.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="mask">
      <h2>Title</h2>

      <p>subtitle</p> <a href="#" class="info">Read More</a>

    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="view">
    <img src="images/m.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="mask">
      <h2>title</h2>

      <p>subtitle</p> <a href="#" class="info">Read More</a>

    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="view">
    <img src="images/p.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="mask">
      <h2>title</h2>

      <p>subtitle</p> <a href="#" class="info">Read More</a>

    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks vanburenx, it's very useful!

Answer (score 0):

Use `nth-child()`

```
.view:nth-child(2) .mask {
 font-family: Arial;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPvgjP

Comment: Thanks very much Paul. That is what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

Given the structure you have I would select the first `article` inside the specific `section` (which has an ID) and go from there:

```
#work article:first-of-type .mask {
    /* your styles here */
 }
```

Oh, by the way, `first-child / first-of-type` etc. are pseudo-*classes* not pseudo-elements.

Comment: Thanks Paulie. Sorry for the spelling, I'm a mess.I'll remember that